# Reading AWS ECS Cluster Tags from dotnet core code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I created tags for an ECS cluster in AWS.
e.g, In the cluster mycluster's tag, I may have such as - 
    ENVIRONMENT=Production

I spent long time searching dotnet core sample code to know how to read the key-value pairs from that ECS cluster tags.

I would be much appreciated if anyone can provide a simple dotnet code how to do it.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found it -

NuGet package `AWSSDK.ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI` is needed for this

```
using Amazon.ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI;
using Amazon.ResourceGroupsTaggingAPI.Model;

public string AWSGetClusterTag()
{
    string ret = "\n demo - ";
    try
    {
        AmazonResourceGroupsTaggingAPIClient client2 = new AmazonResourceGroupsTaggingAPIClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
        GetTagValuesRequest req = new GetTagValuesRequest();
        req.Key = "your tag's key name here";
        GetTagValuesResponse res = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await client2.GetTagValuesAsync(req)).Result;
        List<string> values = res.TagValues;

        ret = ret + " Cluster Tag =  " + req.Key + " : " + values[0];
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       ret = "Exception happened: " + e.Message;
    }
    return ret;
}
```